# Set environment variables in Unix/Linux environment with .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, environment-variables

Is there a way to set an environment variable on a Unix/Linux machine (not process) using .NET Core?

I noticed that I can use Environment.SetEnvironmentVarible for Windows, however, after searching I haven't found an equivalent for a Unix/Linux system.

Comment: I did not see this post. This is the answer I was looking for, so my question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

`Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` also works on Linux, etc.

But be beware only the current process environment variables are set, and not machine or user environment variables like on Windows:

> On .NET Core on macOS and Linux systems, calls to the SetEnvironmentVariable(String, String, EnvironmentVariableTarget) method with a value of EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine or EnvironmentVariableTarget.User are ignored.

From *[Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.8)*.

Comment: I'm actually looking for a way to set the machine variable and not the process variable.

Comment: There's no separation of Process vs User vs Machine variables on Linux. All environment variables are treated the same. And a process can only change the environment variables of itself and any children it spawns.